# Java if statement not being fulfilled

Tags: java, if-statement

I am a bit rusty on my Java.  I have an array with several values one of which is used in an `if` statement.

It's a single character I'm checking and the fact that it's not working leads me to believe it may be a whitespace issue.  The data is coming in from a mysql database and I already tried using `trim()` on the query to get rid of any whitespaces but no luck.

Here's the code:

```
  Payoff payoff=new PlainVanillaPayoff(Option.Type.Put,Strike);
  if(inputData[8] == "C"){
      System.out.println("TypeCall"); // Check to see whether if stmt is ever true.
      payoff=new PlainVanillaPayoff(Option.Type.Call,Strike);
  } else{}
```

The print statement called inside the `if` statement never prints.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does `inputData` array store?

Comment: This question has been asked many times - the 'Related' list on the right has examples. Please do more research before submitting a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are comparing `String`s using `==`. You should use `equals` instead.

```
if(inputData[8].equals("C"))
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the code compiles, the problem is that you're comparing strings with `==`; you should use [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) (or sometimes you want [`equalsIgnoreCase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29)):

```
if(inputData[8].equals("C")){
```

Strings in Java are *objects*, and the `==` operator compares object identity (do two variables contain the same object reference), not the contents of the objects.

Answer (score 2):

if `inputData[8]` is a string you should use the `equals` method instead of `==`:

```
if("C".equals(inputData[8]))
```

also, putting `"C"` first makes sure you won't get a null pointer exception if `inputData[8]1 is null.

Answer (score 1):

If inputData is a `String[]`, you should use `inputdata[8].equals("C")` instead. If its not a `String[]`, this will never fullfill, since they are different types :)

Answer (score 1):

If the type of inputData is `String[]` then I guess your problem is that you are comparing *references* instead of using the `.equals()`-function.

Correct:

```
if(inputData[8].equals("C"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the array a string array or a char array?

In the if clause you need to use " when comparing with strings or ' when doing it with char.

if it's a string try something like this in your if clause

```
stringname.charAt(x) == 'C'
```

Answer (score -1):

If inputData is an array of chars?

```
if(inputData[8] == 'C') should solve it.
```

Otherwise you could try just to see if it does in fact contain "c"

```
Payoff payoff=new PlainVanillaPayoff(Option.Type.Put,Strike);
  if(inputData[8] == "C"){
      System.out.println("TypeCall"); // Check to see whether if stmt is ever true.
      payoff=new PlainVanillaPayoff(Option.Type.Call,Strike);
  } else{ System.out.println("inputData[8] contains: ->" + inputData[8] + "<-");}
```